Webpack split large constants file into chunks
Background
I have a large constants & types file, graphql.ts, produced by https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator . When analyzing the output of webpack's chunks, I get something like this:

graphql.ts - 600KB
Chunk1.ts - 40kb
Chunk2.ts - 80kb
Chunk3.ts - 50kb
etc...

The contents of graphql.ts are a bunch of type & enum definitions, and then a bunch of constant definitions, which are essentially never reused. E.g.
// Type definitions
type MyType = {}
type MyType2 = {}

enum MyEnum {}

// A bunch of constants
const MyQueryDocument1 = { /* A completely isolated JSON object */ };

const MyQueryDocument2 = { /* A completely isolated JSON object */ };

const MyQueryDocument3 = { /* A completely isolated JSON object */ };


// File 1 uses: MyQueryDocument1
// File 2 uses: MyQueryDocument2
// File 3 uses: MyQueryDocument3

Question
How would I split up the graphql.ts file into multiple different parts, which are then included only in the chunks which actually use each part? So that instead of the previous situation, we'd get:

graphql.ts - 30KB (much smaller, since all the constants have been moved to the chunks where they're used, so all that remains are enum definitions)
Chunk1.ts - 70kb (only contains MyQueryDocument1)
Chunk2.ts - 100kb (only contains MyQueryDocument2)
Chunk3.ts - 70kb (only contains MyQueryDocument3)
etc...

I don't need a step-by-step tutorial, but am struggling with even figuring out where to start or where to look. Even just links to guides or code of people doing this would be very helpful.
What I've tried already
Here's what I've tried:

Asking ChatGPT - it keeps contradicting the question

Options to split up the graphql.ts file upstream of webpack don't seem to be available

The near-operations-file setting only produces types (it seems to also be capable of producing hooks and components, but I don't need any of those)
I am already using the "code splitting" features of graphql-code-generator, namely https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/presets/preset-client#reducing-bundle-size - even with that fully enabled, I still get a giant graphql.ts bundle
There's something called graphql-let which might help, but I can't use it because it doesn't support fragments
In case it's relevant, here's the codegen file (with some sensitive information removed):
import type { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: "../schema-folder/*.graphql",
  documents: [
    "src/**/*.{tsx,ts}",
    "!src/gql/**/*",
  ],
  generates: {
    "src/gql/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: [],
      presetConfig: {
        fragmentMasking: { unmaskFunctionName: "myMaskFunction" },
      },
      config: { useTypeImports: true },
    }
  },
}




splitting chunks with chunks: all - https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks

This SO answer says "no", but the answer is from 6 years ago - Can Webpack helps me separate a large single file into smaller pieces? - As a sidenote, if this kind of thing is impossible anyways, there was no reason for me to even attempt to use the "code splitting" feature of graphql-code-generator in the first place.

This Github discussion mentions a very similar question, and has no response - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/13889


Alternative - Force code duplication then rely on tree-shaking
In theory, I think I can:

Somehow force the graphql.ts file to be duplicated into each chunk
Rely on tree-shaking to slim each chunk down
End up with chunks which duplicate the enum definitions but not the constants

But I have no idea how to do step one.
Tedious Alternative - Manually write Babel Plugin + Code post-processor
The only option I can see a concrete path forward with right now is building a bespoke transformation pass which turns the codegen file into a directory, i.e. turning graphql.ts into a folder with:
/graphql/
- index.ts (barrell-exports from all the other files here)
- types.ts
- MyQueryDocument1
- MyQueryDocument2
- MyQueryDocument3

^ This probably wouldn't immediately solve the problem of code-splitting, but it'd then allow me to modify the babel plugin provided by graphql-code-generator to import from graphql/MyQueryDocument1 instead of from graphql.ts

Could you please add the content of the graphql-codegen config file to the question?

Yes, I added the graphql-codegen config file, codegen.ts.
